# Show a set $C$ is closed iff point to set distance is not zero for all points outside of the set

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I think this is an interesting problem

> Suppose that we have $X$ with the metric topology $\tau$ such that $C$
>   is a closed set in $\tau$
>
> Define the point to set distance as
>
> $$dist(x, C) = \inf\{d(x,y)|y \in C\}$$
>
> Then $C$ is closed iff $dist(x,C) \neq 0 \quad \forall x \in X \backslash C$

**First:** ($C$ is closed $\implies dist(x,C) \neq 0, \forall x \in X \backslash C)$

Let $C$ be closed, then $X \backslash C$ has to be open, then for all $x \in X \backslash C$, there exists a ball $B(x,\epsilon) \subset X \backslash C$ with $\epsilon >0$. So $dist(x,C) = \epsilon >0$

**Second:** ($dist(x,C) \neq 0, \forall x \in X \backslash C \implies $C is closed $)$

Let $dist(x,C) \neq 0, \forall x \in X \backslash C$, then $\exists \epsilon_x$ such that $B(x, \epsilon_x) \subset X \backslash C$. Take arbitrary union of all balls we have 
$$U = \bigcup_{x \in X \backslash C} B(x, \epsilon_x)$$ which is open, then $X \backslash U = C$ is closed.

Can someone check if my proofs are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your **First** proof is perfect, except the final sentence should read "So $\operatorname{dist}(x, C) \geq \epsilon$", instead of strict equality.  Your **Second** proof is fine, but could be shorter.  In your first sentence, you write:

> Let $dist(x,C) \neq 0, \forall x \in X \backslash C$, then $\exists \epsilon_x$ such that $B(x, \epsilon_x) \subset X \backslash C$.

At this point, without any extra work required, you've shown $X \setminus C$ is open, so it follows immediately that the complement, $C$, is closed.